# The image of product of two linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ and $B$ be two linear transformations.

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial such that $p(AB)=0$, and $q(x)=xp(x)$, then prove that $q(AB)=0$ .

Comment: $AB(0) = 0$ ...?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $q(AB) = (AB)p(AB) = (AB)(0) = 0$.